# How can I rewrite this method to remove redundant if statement?

Tags: java, performance

How can I rewrite this method to maximum code efficiency and minimize the code length?

**Note**: `HEADER` is a constant defined before.

```
private static URL getURL(String OS, String type, String size) {
        String prefix = "";
        String prefixLarge = "";
        if (type.equals("image")) {
            prefix = HEADER + "/image";
            prefixLarge = HEADER + "/image_large";
        } else {
            prefix = HEADER + "/file";
            prefixLarge = HEADER + "/file_raw";
        }
        String suffix = ".zip";
        String url = "";
        if (OS.contains("Win7.32bit")) {
            // win7-32bit system
            url = prefix + "Win7.32bit" + suffix;
            if (size.contains("origin")) {
                url = prefixLarge + "Win7.32bit" + suffix;
            }
        } else if (OS.contains("Win7.64bit")) {
            // win7-64bit system
            url = prefix + "Win7.64bit" + suffix;
            if (size.contains("origin")) {
                url = prefixLarge + "Win7.64bit" + suffix;
            }
        } else if (OS.contains("WinXP")) {
            // winxp-32bit system
            url = prefix + "WinXP" + suffix;
            if (size.contains("origin")) {
                url = prefixLarge + "WinXP" + suffix;
            }
        } else if (OS.contains("WinXP.64bit")) {
            // winxp-64bit system
            url = prefix + "WinXP.64bit" + suffix;
            if (size.contains("origin")) {
                url = prefixLarge + "WinXP.64bit" + suffix;
            }
        } else if (OS.contains("10.04")) {
            // ubuntu10.04 system
            url = prefix + "ubuntu10.04" + suffix;
            if (size.contains("origin")) {
                url = prefixLarge + "ubuntu10.04" + suffix;
            }
        } else if (OS.contains("12.04")) {
            // ubuntu12.04 system
            url = prefix + "ubuntu12.04" + suffix;
            if (size.contains("origin")) {
                url = prefixLarge + "ubuntu12.04" + suffix;
            }
        }
        return url;
    }
```

Comment: have you considered using switch?

Comment: @KyelJmD I don't think `switch` will work in this case.

Comment: @A.R.S. It could if its `JDK 7`. [Strings in switch Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

Comment: @smit @KyelJmD ... But `contains` in switch statement? Doubt it.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen was about to comment same thing.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen @Pankaj, You guys are right, just wanted to pointed out that `JDK 7` allows `string in switch`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an array of `Strings` containing all the OS names. Then iterate over that array with a `for` loop.

Like this:

```java
String[] osNames = { "Win7.32bit", "Win7.64bit", "10.04" };
String[] osTypes = { "Win7.32bit", "Win7.64bit", "ubuntu10.04" };
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(osNames.length, osTypes.length); i++) {
    if (OS.contains(osName[i])) {
        url = prefix + osType[i] + suffix;
        if (size.contains("origin")) {
            url = prefixLarge + osType[i] + suffix;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is still room for improvement, e.g. using a `StringBuilder` instead of `String`. Concatenating the URL similar as [written by @user1950086](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14166833/1277252) (means: without that many temporary variables). You could use a `Map` or other type of associative object instead of parallel arrays [as mentioned by @GreyBeardedGeek](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14166742/1277252). My intention was to show you how you can get rid of the many code duplications. I think in Java it is more important to keep code redundancy low than optimizing for performance first.

Answer (score 3):

```
    private static Map <String, String> osMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static {
      osMap.put("Win7.32bit", "Win7.32bit");
      osMap.put("Win7.64bit", "Win7.64bit");
      osMap.put("WinXP", "WinXP");
      osMap.put("WinXP.64bit", "WinXP.64bit");
      osMap.put("10.04", "ubuntu10.04");
      osMap.put("12.04", "ubuntu12.04");
    }

    private static URL getURL(String os, String type, String size) {
        String prefix = "";
        String prefixLarge = "";
        if (type.equals("image")) {
            prefix = HEADER + "/image";
            prefixLarge = HEADER + "/image_large";
        } else {
            prefix = HEADER + "/file";
            prefixLarge = HEADER + "/file_raw";
        }
        String suffix = ".zip";
        String url = "";
        String systemType = "";

        for(String key : osMap.keySet()) {
           if(os.contains(key) {           
              url = prefix + osMap.get(key) + suffix;
              if (size.contains("origin")) {
                url = prefixLarge + osMap.get(key) + suffix;
              }
              break;
           }
        }
        return url;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see Moritz's answer until after I submitted this - basically the same thing, but with a Map instead of parallel arrays;

Comment: First I thought I leave the implementation to the TO but then I saw other implementation attempts and decided to provide my own ;-)

Comment: +1 because I prefer the map approach to parallel arrays. Parallel arrays always have a risk of getting out of step, especially if more operating systems and versions are added.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static URL getURL(String OS, String type, String size) {

    return  HEADER
            +
            size.contains("origin") 
                            ? ((type.equals("image") ? "/image_large" : "/file_raw" ))
                            : ((type.equals("image") ? "/image" : "/file" )) 
            +
            OS.contains("Win7.32bit")   ? "Win7.32bit" :
            OS.contains("Win7.64bit")   ? "Win7.64bit" : 
            OS.contains("WinXP.64bit")  ? "WinXP.64bit" :       
            OS.contains("WinXP")        ? "WinXP" : 
            OS.contains("10.04")        ? "ubuntu10.04" : 
            OS.contains("12.04")        ? "ubuntu12.04" : 
            ""
            +
            ".zip";
}
```

Comment: This is really hell of a work. Hats of to your imagination and creativity.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] osNames={"Win7.32bit", "Win7.64bit"};
        for(String os : osNames){
            if(OS.contains(os)){
                url = prefix + os + suffix;
                if (size.contains("origin")) {
                    url = prefixLarge + os + suffix;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

This is part of the code to remove if-else conditions. Notice the break statement.

Comment: Maybe he spotted that the construction of url isn't exactly the same. Compare `ubuntu12.10` and `12.10`. However, I'm one of the upvoters :)

Comment: hmm may be, in that case you need to add 2-3 more lines of code. But we should leave something for actual developer too. :)

Comment: replace `String[] osNames` with `Map<String,String> osSubstringToFullName` and you are in business